# speed of custom functions with numpy's arrays vs standard python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I'm using numpy to create a multi array for an image as in array[height][width][sample] --> [x,y,z]. For each vector I then run a custom (standard python) function.

When I use `numpy.apply_along_axis(myfunc, array, -1)` and time it, it is however about 3 times **slower** than when I turn the array into a python list (`array.tolist()`) and then do the python way with three nested loops and call `myfunc([x,y,z])` from there.

Does that make sense or must there be an error in my code? In more general terms: Is there a time benefit of turning any python list into a numpy array and using apply_along_axis-like functions with custom python functions?

Comment: Iteration on lists is faster.  `numpy` is faster when applying numpy methods to the whole array.  That moves the iterations into compiled code.

Comment: `apply_along_axis` is slower than an explicit iteration on the (other) array dimensions.  For one thing it does a trial calculation to return a dtype.  But more generally, python level iteration of arrays is slower than equivalent iteration on lists because extracting individual values from an is more complex.  Use `numpy` only if you can take advantage of its compiled 'whole-array' methods.